# Agregar referencias a proyecto Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows

Acabo de descargar un proyecto desde el TeamFoundation y las referencias del proyecto no están, ¿cómo puedo agregarlas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado instalar paquetes desde la consola y me sale por ejemplo este error. ¿Puede ser que falte alguna característica del Visual Studio por instalar?

```
Install-Package : No se encuentra el paquete 'StarIO_Extension'
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package StarIO_Extension
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: sera que se agregaron por medio de nuget? si es asi al compilar se deberian descargar automaticamente. Puedes ver un packages.config, si es asi valida en el xml de este que librerias se mencionan

Comment: Active la restauracion de paqutes nuget ..y lo hizo correctamente , pero aun asi continua apareciendo el icono y mensajes de advertencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valida en las opciones del `Visual Studio` que tengas la opcion que habilita a nuget descargar los paquetes

entonces al compilar deberian descargarse los que se mencionen en el `packages.config`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya estaba de esa manera _:::

Comment: puedes ver la carpeta "packages" dentro de la estructura de la solucion? si es asi hay algo dentro de esta? porque se supone que nuget es alli donde descarga las librerias